# How do I merge four windows in to four evenly-spaced panes?

Tags: tmux

I have four windows called PP1, PP2, PP3, and PP4. I would like to join them so that they would look something like this:

```
-----------------
|   |   |   |   |
|PP1|PP2|PP3|PP4|
|   |   |   |   |
-----------------
```

Currently I'm using `join-pane`, but I am unsure of how to make them evenly spaced.

```
tmux join-pane -h -s PP2 -t PP1
tmux join-pane -h -s PP3 -t PP1
tmux join-pane -h -s PP4 -t PP1
```

I've also tried adding this to the end of the script, but to no avail:

```
tmux select-layout -t PP1 even-horizontal
```

Comment: You are confusing the concepts here. What you are trying to do is merge windows together in a nice, evenly spaced layouts. Tmux sessions are a completely different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the keyboard, you can press your activation key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> by default) and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. Alternatively, repeated <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> will cycle through the common layout options.

Comment: `Alt-2` for vertical separation.